# Creating a dynamic resource pool for yarn through Cloudera Manager REST api

Tags: hadoop-yarn, cloudera, cloudera-cdh, cloudera-manager

I'm currently creating resource pools through the web UI as per
https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-6-x/topics/cm_mc_resource_pools.html#concept_xkk_l1d_wr__section_utc_gbl_vl

Since I have a large number of resource pools to create I want to do this using some script.

Is there any way this can be done through cloudera manager REST api?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to GET the yarn configuration through cloudera manager api. As specified by [http://cloudera.github.io/cm_api/apidocs/v14/path__clusters_-clusterName-*services*-serviceName-_config.html](http://cloudera.github.io/cm_api/apidocs/v14/path__clusters_-clusterName-_services_-serviceName-_config.html), e.g. https://cm-web-url:7183/api/v14/clusters/cluster1/services/yarn/config, if you're using yarn fair-scheduler, then look for field yarn_fs_scheduled_allocations. After editing you can PUT the configuration back.

I also asked Cloudera support and the official answer was that there is no fine-grained REST API for this.

This is as of CDH 5.9.0.